# Como criar um cardview com "slide" (semelhante ao do Nubank)?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Eu estou tentando fazer um layout semelhante ao `cardview` da tela principal do nubank, porém, não estou conseguindo encontrar referencia para me basear. O que eu estou com problemas de encontrar, é como deixar o `cardview` com esses "pontinhos". Alguém pode me indicar algum material, ou ainda me dar dicas de como fazer ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

Utilizei um `ViewPager` contento um `SpringDotsIndicator`. Criei arquivos de layout separados para os `CardView`, e os inflei em um `Fragment`.

Adicione essa implementação no Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:2.1.2'
```

Adicione esse trecho no `activity_main`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.SpringDotsIndicator
        android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:dotsColor="@color/white"
        app:dotsCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:dotsSize="10dp"
        app:dotsSpacing="4dp"
        app:dotsWidthFactor="2.5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Obs: Adicionei tudo dentro de um `LinearLayout`.

No seu `MainActivity.java` não esqueça de adicionar:

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
dotsIndicator = findViewById(R.id.dots_indicator);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
dotsIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```